# How to import .csv file with descriptions to a gallery in media?

Tags: csv

I have this CSV file that I want to import into an image gallery I have in my "media" tab. Images are named like `79.jpg`, `80.jpg`, `81.jpg`, and so on.

My CSV file is ordered like this:

```
id;;creator;poster;dato_inn;tid_inn;dato_tatt;info_hvor;info_keyw;info_om;info_tittel

79;;John Føreland;Øvrebø;01.08.2006;13:41:29;01.08.2006;Øvrebø;buss;En av de første bussene produsert ved Førelands karosserifabrikk;Buss fra Føreland karosseri
```

With 79 as the `id`.

Can I link it to the image names and make this import smooth and simple?
Or am I maybe stuck, copy/pasting more than 600 descriptions?

Comment: Same problem, I have hundreds of descriptions to update. 6 years without even an answer to this incredibly simple question. Amazing.